# Google Colab: Re-setting up Python Modules

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, google-colaboratory

I recently removed the pre-installed python modules **tensorflow==1.9.0-rc1** and **keras==2.1.6** from [Google Colab](https://colab.research.google.com) to test the older versions of TF and Keras. Now I want to come back to the default settings/modules. So, I re installed both of them using following commands.

```
!pip uninstall -y tensorflow keras
!pip install tensorflow==1.9.0-rc1 keras==2.1.6
```

Now, GPU and code are Running (on GPU - checked in Notebook Settings), but the same code takes 40x extra time. So, is there a way to go back to the default settings? or did I make a mistake removing the default packages?

Please guide (I'm new in Machine Learning)

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply select `Tools/Restart Runtime` and any changes you made to the runtime will be eliminated. Every time Colab times out your session you get a brand new instance.

Comment: **Every time Colab times out your session you get a brand-new instance** Is there any way to start from my last session? Like if I install a lot of packages in a session than it might be time-waste to reinstall it every new session @Thomson Comer

Answer (score 0):

> `Tools/Factory reset runtime`

will delete install files as well and let you re-install the wanted version easily